# with tokbox with an event with multople video chats would the camera permission end after each chat?

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I'm considering using tokbox for a video networking platform I am building, but have one cncern that I would like an answer to first.

By default with tokbox does the browser camera permission last only for one chat at a time.

Or if there is a networking event with multiple video chats will the camera permission for the website session last till the event ends?

I've seen a networking platform using tokbox have it work so that one permission lasts the entire event.

But I've seen this being required for each chat as well.  WOuld someone know what was the default behavior of tokbox?

Or is there special coding or API to make it work one way or the other?

Answer (score 0):

I know for browsers like chrome, the default behaviour is to ask for permission to allow for access to audio and camera the first time the user logs in to the app and it does well to remember that permissions were enabled for that site and so each time one makes another request for a video call to that same site after initially enabling, it does not ask again for permissions.

So yes it will last throughout the call (thus I have only tested this in chrome).

The permissions will also fail to be accepted if the user's camera or audio is already in use. So one must just ensure that audio or camera is not already in use.